# How do I correctly calculate the delta (difference) between two CGAffineTransform matrices?

Tags: objective-c, ios, matrix, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I've been playing around with the Stanford Uni Lectures / WWDC video that shows you how to create a gesture to pinch/zoom simultaneously. It returns a `CGAffineTransform` that you then apply to the UIView.

This all works fine, but I'm trying to make it a bit more fluid and add some deceleration to the code. I've tried to do this by storing the transformation matrix on each `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` call, and then when I receive `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` I store the delta between the last Changed and Ended matrices:

```
- (void)handleTransform:(TransformGestureRecognizer *)transformRecognizer
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = transformRecognizer.transform;

    // cancel any previous animation updates
    [UIView cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(decelerateView:) object:transformRecognizer.view];

    if(transformRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transformRecognizer.view.transform, transform);
        transformRecognizer.transform = transform;
    }
    else if(transformRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        changingTransform = transform;
    }
    else if(transformRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // get transform difference
        releaseTransformDiff.a = (transform.a - changingTransform.a);
        releaseTransformDiff.b = (transform.b - changingTransform.b);
        releaseTransformDiff.c = (transform.c - changingTransform.c);
        releaseTransformDiff.d = (transform.d - changingTransform.d);
        releaseTransformDiff.tx = (transform.tx - changingTransform.tx);
        releaseTransformDiff.ty = (transform.ty - changingTransform.ty);

        // start updating deceleration animation
        [self performSelector:@selector(decelerateView:) withObject:transformRecognizer.view afterDelay:1.0/60.0];
    }

    transformRecognizer.view.transform = transform;
}
```

Then, I have a `decelerateView:` method for animating the deceleration:

```
#define DECELERATION_RATE 0.9

- (void)decelerateView:(UIView *)view
{
    releaseTransformDiff.a = releaseTransformDiff.a * DECELERATION_RATE;
    releaseTransformDiff.b = releaseTransformDiff.b * DECELERATION_RATE;
    releaseTransformDiff.c = releaseTransformDiff.c * DECELERATION_RATE;
    releaseTransformDiff.d = releaseTransformDiff.d * DECELERATION_RATE;
    releaseTransformDiff.tx = releaseTransformDiff.tx * DECELERATION_RATE;
    releaseTransformDiff.ty = releaseTransformDiff.ty * DECELERATION_RATE;

    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(view.transform.a + releaseTransformDiff.a, 
                                           view.transform.b + releaseTransformDiff.b, 
                                           view.transform.c + releaseTransformDiff.c, 
                                           view.transform.d + releaseTransformDiff.d, 
                                           view.transform.tx + releaseTransformDiff.tx,
                                           view.transform.ty + releaseTransformDiff.ty);
    [self performSelector:@selector(decelerateView:) withObject:view afterDelay:1.0/60.0];
}
```

This works sometimes, but other times it stops abruptly, and virtually never decelerates any rotation spins I do... I guess I'm not calculating the delta correctly for the two matrices. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A CGAffineTransformation is a simplified data structure representing a 3 x 3 matrix:

```
|a  b  0|
|c  d  0|
|tx ty 1|
```

A point is transformed by multiplying the a 3 x 1 matrix by the above matrix

```
                      |a  b  0|
[x' y' 1] = [x y 1] X |c  d  0|
                      |tx ty 1|
```

To create a scaling affine transformation set a to the factor by which to scale the x axis, and d to the factor by which to scale the y axis. To create a translation affine transformation set tx to the value to move along the x axis, and ty to the value to move along the y axis.

The technique used in this question would work for affine transformations that were merely scaling or translation transformations (or a combination of these two types of transformations). That's because the four values affected do change linearly and independently.

To create a rotation affine transformation for the angle A set a to cos A, b to sin A, c to -sin A, and d to cos A. Since sin and cos are not linear functions, the delta change proposed in the question will not work correctly. To complicate matters even further, the combination of two transformations is the multiplication of the two matrices representing those transformations. With rotations involved, the resulting matrix will not differ linearly from a matrix that will result in a slightly different transform.

The way to build delta transforms is to change the inputs to your transformation building function calls, not to directly futz with the resulting matrices.

Comment: That's what I feared :) unfortunately the transformation code is very complicated, doing some pretty hardcore trigonometry-type maths... It might take a while to pull it apart, if I can at all! Perhaps I should post the code above? Thanks!